# mysql limit clause not working alongside php bindvalue

Tags: php, mysql

After attempting to create a pagination, I noticed that **PHP**'s `bindValue` does not work when using alongside **MySQL**'s `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` clauses.

This is pretty strange considering it'll work anywhere else within **MySQL** (at least as far as I'm aware). For example, this works completely fine:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo = ? AND bar = ?
```

However, when attempting something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ?, ?
```

It will return an empty object.

This is how I'm executing my queries (please note that this is all simplified, and the functions that I'm using are all apart of a `class`):

```
// query function
function query($sql, $params){
    if($query = $pdo->prepare($sql)){
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)){
            foreach($params as $param){
                $query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if($query->execute()){
            return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

// executing a query (this will return an empty object)
$query = query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ?, ?", array(0, 10));
var_dump($query);
```

Can't seem to figure this one out, so all help is appreciated,

Cheers.

Comment: @lolbas I tried `$query->bindParam($x, $param, PDO::PARAM_INT);` (and `PARAM_STR`) to no avail.

Comment: this is not what linked answer suggests.

Comment: @lolbas Ah! You're correct, did not notice the ampersand. Will give it a shot :)

Answer (score 0):

You Params will be included as Strings. Use a constant to tell bindValue to bind the value as an int.

```
$query->bindParam(2, $x, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: MySQL is fine handling params passed as strings. It is unlikely this is the cause of issue.